# SSRS does not work when input parameter has a + sign

Tags: select, reporting-services, filter, report, input-parameters

I'm creating a report which has as input parameters: id and name. These parameters are used in the where clause of the select from which I get the records to display in my list.

The problem is that if there is a + sign into the name the parameter (that I print on the page to display the filter) name appears with a space instead:

Input parameter = "record+story"
Parameter shown in report: "record story"

So the result of the select is empty, since the name doesn't match!

What am I missing?

EDIT: I open the report through a client application, based on VB6. There is a main page with a table and a list od ids, when I click on a row of the list it redirects me to an IE page performing the filtering and showing only the needed data. 
The parameters are: id - Integer, and name - text.

When it opens the IE page I see that if the name contains a plus sign there appears instead a space, which of course is wrong, therefore the resulting report is empty.

I already tried to add the System.Web reference to VB6 in the client application, but it doesn't work.

Here a picture to clarify what I mean.

[image]

Thank you

C.

Comment: How are you populating the parameters? Also what data types are you using for your parameters?

Comment: As suggested by @BradSyputa in the provided answer you have to encode your URL.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got the solution. I only need to encode my parameter so that the + sign is read as a + sign. This is achieved by using the hex value in the code behind:

example: namewithplussign ==> replace(namewithplussign , "+", "%2b")